# Why ->latest method in model method read all rows from related table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel 9 I got last value in related CurrencyHistory table

```
$currencies = Currency
    ::getByActive(true)
    ->withCount('currencyHistories')
    ->with('latestCurrencyHistory')
    ->orderBy('ordering', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

In model app/Models/Currency.php I have :

```
public function latestCurrencyHistory()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CurrencyHistory')->latest();
}
```

But checking generated sql I see lines like :

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM `currency_histories` 
    WHERE `currency_histories`.`currency_id` in (8, 13, 16, 19, 27, 30) 
    ORDER BY `created_at` desc
```

I suppose this code is raised by latestCurrencyHistory method and wonder can
I set some limit 1 condition here, as resulting data are too big.

Thanks!

Comment: That code is not raised by withCount() as that would have select count(*), this is by the with query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query is correct. As you eager load your relation for the **collection** of currencies using `with` method, you load `currency_histories` for all of your `Currency` models in collection.

If you dump the result, you will have currencies with IDs: 8, 13, 16, 19, 27, 30 and one `latestCurrencyHistory` (if present) for each.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. But resulting sql : 
   SELECT * 
    FROM `currency_histories` 
    WHERE `currency_histories`.`currency_id` in (8, 13, 16, 19, 27, 30) 
    ORDER BY `created_at` desc 
        
got a lot of data 

I would like to get only 1 row for ANY of 8, 13, 16, 19, 27, 30 subset.
If I try 
return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CurrencyHistory')->latest()->limit(1);
I got only one row for all subset...
Can I do it with eloquent ?

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean. Well, then your relation is wrongly described, because in fact you have "1 to many" relationship, not "1 to 1". You will not be able to limit results using `with` this way.

Comment: Have I to use     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CurrencyHistory')->latest();  ?

Comment: If I see correctly, you have `currencyHistories` relation as well, which is the same. You should access the latest history entry using `$currency->currencyHistories()->latest()->first()`

Comment: Yes, I have 2 similar currencyHistories relations , in the second I tried to get only 1 last row.
I tried to change :

    public function latestCurrencyHistory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CurrencyHistory')->latest()->first();//->limit(1);
    }

But got ERROR: Call to undefined method App\Models\CurrencyHistory::addEagerConstraints() {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): 
Your piece of code seems valid, but how use it 1 request. I would like to escape using of ->map method...

Comment: Well, as I told you will not be able to do so in 1 query, because you can't get only 1 record by eager loading if multiple possible.  All you can do is load all and then take first as they will be ordered by `latest`.